# How to check that a countdown label has the wanted values with Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I have an slider that controls the amount of time a countdown will have.

The countdown is showed in a label to the user. So, if I set it to 5, the label will show 5, then 4, then 3 until 0, the initial value is `-`.

I want to test this with Cypress. But I am not sure which is the correct way to do it without creating a flacky test.

Is there a recommended way to "watch" and specific item changes?

Answer (score 0):

I too am looking for a good way to listen for element changes. But I think in your scenario maybe you can get away through the countdown timer with something like this:

```
const count = 5;
const countdownTime = 1000;
let expectedCurrentNumber = count - 1;

do {
  cy.contains('countdownLabel', expectedCurrentNumber, { timeout: countdownTime });
} while (--expectedCurrentNumber > 0);

cy.contains('countdownLabel', '-', { timeout: countdownTime });
```